# Reactjs How preview image and get image file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I write this code for preview image before upload but the problem I can either preview image or get image file. I can't get both functionality at a time preview image and file for upload. If I replace `return URL.createObjectURL(file);` to `retun file` then I am getting file for upload but image preview not working. How to use both functionality ? any suggestion? here is my code:

```
export const MultiImageUpload = () => {
  const [selectedImages, setSelectedImages] = useState([]);

  const onSelectFile = (event) => {
    const selectedFiles = event.target.files;
    const selectedFilesArray = Array.from(selectedFiles);
 
     
    const imagesArray = selectedFilesArray.map((file) => {
      
      return URL.createObjectURL(file);
      //return file 
      
    });
    
   
     
    setSelectedImages((previousImages) => previousImages.concat(imagesArray));
    
    
    // FOR BUG IN CHROME
    event.target.value = "";
  };

  function deleteHandler(image) {
    setSelectedImages(selectedImages.filter((e) => e !== image));

    URL.revokeObjectURL(image);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use both url (base64 string  )and file (blob) at the same time,Like this

```
//this will  hold base64 url of images
const [selectedImagesURL, setSelectedImagesURL] = useState([]);
//this will hold file blob
const [selectedImages, setSelectedImages] = useState([]);
```

Now your on change handler should updated both url and images array

```
const onSelectFile = (event) => {
const selectedFiles = event.target.files;
const selectedFilesArray = Array.from(selectedFiles);
const imagesURLArray = selectedFilesArray.map((file) => {
  return URL.createObjectURL(file);
});
 
setSelectedImages((previousImages) => previousImages.concat(selectedFilesArray));
setSelectedImagesURL((previousImagesURL) => previousImagesURL.concat(imagesURLArray));


// FOR BUG IN CHROME
event.target.value = "";
};
```

Then use `selectedImagesURL` to preview the images and  `selectedImages` to upload.

Hope this will help!